# How to call child function from parent class

Tags: c++

For example i have

```
class A
{
  void Afunction();
};
```

and i have

```
#include "A.h"
class B: public A
{
   void Function();
   
};
```

```
    #include "B.h"
    class C
    {
       void UpdateStuff();
       void CreateStuff();
       B* Stuff;
    }
```

I need call `CreateStuff();`  from `Afunction();` but I can't just `#include "C.h"` Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: `Function()` is a member function, you need `B` object to call it. Where would this object come from?

Comment: There is no link from an A object back to a B object.

Comment: There is no child or parent here since there is no inheritance.

Comment: how do you call `Function();` outside of `AFunction();` ? If you want to call `Function();` from within `AFunction();` you do the same

Comment: "but I can't just #include "C.h"" why not? there is a (indirect) cyclic dependency, is there another reason why you can't use the include? The question would be more clear if you would post a [mcve] of the code that you would like to write but cannot together with the resulting error message, because "I can't" doesnt explain the problem

Comment: @TedLyngmo the parent-child analogy is also used in patterns where there is no inheritance. Actually with inheritance the analogy is rather odd, because "every child is a parent" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @idclev463035818 That's true. I interpreted it as OP was thinking about the inheritance kind but I guess it could have been the other kind just as well.

Comment: A `B` or `A` object still has no link to a `C` object. You need to sort that out first.

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can call child function using a pointer or a reference of Parent class that points or references the child object.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
   virtual void Function()                            //Defination
   { std::cout << "Super_class: A\n"; }
   virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B
{
   virtual void Function() { std::cout << "Child_class\n"; }
};

int main()
{
 A *obj1 = new B;
 obj1->Function();
 B obj2;
 obj2.A::Function();      //Calling to Parent class function(A)
 obj2.Function();         //Calling to Child class function(B)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're unable to achieve that with your current code design. Class A does not inherit from Class C and `Afunction()` doesn't get passed a reference to Class C.

You can either make A inherit C like you have with B inheriting A or you can pass a reference to the function like so

```
class A
{
  void Afunction(C* CObject);
};
```

Furthermore you also can't call child class functions from parent class functions when talking about inheritance. Inheritance works from Top down not from the bottom up.

For example

```
class A
{
    void Afunction();
};

class B : public A
{
    void Afunction()
    {
        A::Afunction(); // This is valid
    }
}
```

This is not valid code.

```
class A
{
    void Afunction()
    {
        B::Afunction(); // This is not valid as A::Afunction() does not inherit from B::Afunction() 
    }

};

class B : public A
{
    void Afunction();
}
```